# Svg for .NET between 1.6 and 1.7 loses resolution on PNG files?

Tags: javascript, c#, svg

Today I updated Svg in my C# project from 1.6.0 to 1.7.0. Under 1.6.0 the PNG images I was generating faithfully reflected the complexity of the SVG images I was giving it to render. Now, in v1.7.0 I'm getting lower resolution images from the same SVG data.

Was there an API change? This is part of the code which I was using. What needs to be changed?

```
var svgs = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");
....
int svgsLength = svgs.length;
for (var i = 0; i < svgsLength; i++)
{
    var svgText = svgs[i].outerHTML;
    XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.LoadXml(svgText);
    var sampleDoc = SvgDocument.Open(xd);
    ....
    catch (Exception e) { }
    var bitmap = sampleDoc.Draw();
    bitmap.Save(pngFile);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest raising an issue with: https://github.com/vvvv/SVG as that is the project's github location.

Comment: Good point. Now done. Thanks for the heads-up: it's been ... a ... day.

Comment: updates that break things - always a fun day had!